# Windows 7 laptop comes in hibernation from sleep and can't boot after that

Tags: windows-7, boot, troubleshooting, sleep, hibernate

I have a new OS installation on my laptop, Windows 7. I put PC into  `hibernation` state. After that it can't boot from this state normally (error 0xC000009A on black screen), I have to perform `cold start` (select "Delete all hibernation data..."). Laptop was connected to power, so it wasn't discharged. 
Previously, I have Windows 8.1 on this PC and there weren't troubles with sleep and hibernation neither. I had another troubles...
All drivers are installed from official vendor web-site and BIOS is updated.
Where should I dig to find the cause of this behavior?
I've already tried:

1. Disable (`powercfg -h off`) and enable (`powercfg -h on`) hibernation with reboot between these steps
2. The same as in 1., but with checkdisk scheduled after reboot (`chkdsk /r`)
3. `sfc /scannnow` to check system files integrity
4. Delete Anti-Virus

Didn't helped me...

Comment: [Some tips here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/unable-to-resume-windows-7-from-hibernation/dedc3a07-9c35-4c13-b96d-1cda877de449)

Comment: This doesn't helps me.
Also, I updated question.

Comment: More tips here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-boot-manager-your-computer-cant-come-out/a3170a6f-2962-45ac-8005-bde7abb35831
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/455135/cannot-hibernate-0xc000009a/ and http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=278650 

In short, check your disk. bootloader, filesystem, and system file integrity.

Comment: Same advises...